# Closed form for the series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\exp(\cos(n))}{n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, integration, closed-form

Does anyone have any ideas on how to find a closed form for the following expression? It comes up when trying to bound a particular integral. The sum is:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{\cos(n)}}{n!}$$

Thank you very much for your thoughts.

Comment: Somehow I doubt there is a closed form - I certainly don't know of one. Trivial bounds are
$e^{-e}$ and
$e^e$ since $-1 < \cos(n) < 1$. Sorry, nothing more occurs to me.

Comment: In the future, please try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.*

Comment: @martycohen: tighter bounds would be $1$ (since $e^{\cos(n)}\ge1/e$) and $e^2$ (since $e^{\cos(n)}\le e$).

Answer (score 3):

I highly doubt there is any reasonable closed form expression. However, since you are just trying to bound some integral, this may be useful.

Denote the partial sums by $\displaystyle S_{m}=\sum_{n=0}^{m} \frac{e^{\cos(n)}}{n!}$. Note that $\displaystyle S_{\infty}=S_{m}+\sum_{m+1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{\cos(n)}}{n!}$. We can bound the error term above and below as follows:

$$\sum_{m+1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{\cos(n)}}{n!} \ge \frac{1}{e}\sum_{m+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}=1-\frac{\Gamma(m+1,1)}{\Gamma(m+1)}=E_{m}$$
$$\sum_{m+1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{\cos(n)}}{n!} \le e\sum_{m+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}=e^{2}E_{m}$$

Since we are summing positive terms, we may bound the final sum as follows:

$$S_{m}+E_{m} \le S_{\infty} \le S_{m}+e^{2}E_{m}$$

The majority of the sum is deposited in the first few terms, so plugging in $m=5$ yields the following decent, rigorous bounds:

$$2.14158 \le S_{\infty} \le 2.14538$$

Numerically, $S_{\infty} \approx 2.14506$.

Comment: @ Jackson You bounds are wrong. Notice that already the first partial sum $e\simeq 2.71828$ is greater that your upper bound, and the sum has only positive terms. The first five partial sums are $\{2.71828,4.43481,4.7646,4.82653,4.8482\}$ and $S_{\infty}\simeq 4.863340835286253$

Comment: @ Jackson Your bounds are wrong. Notice that already the first partial sum $e\simeq 2.71828$ is greater that your upper bound, and the sum has only positive terms. The first five partial sums are $\{2.71828,4.43481,4.7646,4.82653,4.8482\}$ and $S_{\infty}\simeq 4.863340835286253$